# How to set Radio button selection programatically in react material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using radio button group from [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/radio-button). I can set defaultSelected to have a default selection but once rendered, i won't be able to set it programatically. It only changes when you click the radio. Is this something which we can do with material-ui?

Comment: can you share your code so that we can check

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In react components can be either controlled or uncontrolled. Controlled means that you set that component value yourself and you keep the value in the parent component as well in a state or prop. While uncontrolled component means that you only set a default value and you let the component handle the rest.

Now in most cases you would need a component that edits a value to send that value out to its parent, for sending a server request or just storing this value in the application state, so I would argue that in most cases you should use a controlled component.

To do this in material-ui instead of setting the 'defaultSelected' propery use the 'valueSelected' property and set it to a prop or state variable, also use the 'onChange' callback to set the state value or propagate the callback outside where you will eventually change the state in a controller component or update the application state in some store.

Comment: Thanks. I already had a state to track the selection, was using it for default selection. I was under the impression that valueSelected is to get the value of selection :) my bad

Comment: changing from defaultSelected to valueSelected resolved my issue. Thanks a ton!!!!